# Добавление объекта в windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как мне добавить вот сюда еще один объект с другим фоном. Как на скрине ниже этого[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Познакомьтесь `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое. ваш комментарий очень важен для меня. обязательно учту. я в виндовс формс только начал разбираться. еще раз спасибо